# Code style checker

Tags: java

I am working on a android app and i am new to Java. Can some one suggest code style checker for Java? I am using eclipse IDE.

Comment: How, is this related to android?

Comment: Since are there can android related style

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can definitely recommend **[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)**.

Checkstyle is a great plugin that takes care of a wide amount of things, such as intendation, variable/class/method names, JavaDoc conventions, number of parameters allowed in a method, and so on. I use it myself and it's a very simple way to make sure that your code at least looks consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Start with Eclipse's built-in tools:
Preferences → Compiler → Errors/Warnings

Also, FindBugs generates a tolerable set of warnings--that is, it isn't overwhelming, doesn't try to find fault with every single line.